# strange variables and functions definition in openwrt makefile

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I am reading the makefile of openwrt, original file can be found here:
https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/target/linux/ramips/image/Makefile#L589

I cannot understand these lines:

```
BuildFirmware/Default8M/squashfs=$(call BuildFirmware/OF,$(1),$(2),$(3),$(ralink_default_fw_size_8M),$(4))
BuildFirmware/Default8M/initramfs=$(call BuildFirmware/OF/initramfs,$(1),$(2),$(3),$(4))

Image/Build/Profile/MT7620a=$(call BuildFirmware/Default8M/$(1),$(1),mt7620a,MT7620a)
```

Q1. $(1), $(2)..... Where do these variables come from? How can I assign values to them? 
Q2. If $(1) is "squashfs", does it mean the 3rd line is calling the "function" defined in the 1st line? The argument list does not match, in my opinion.
Q3. the slash "/" in these variable names seem odd. Is it the good way to define a variable? I think we can change it to :
    Image_Build_Profile_MT7620a

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: The variables `$(1)`, `$(2)` and so on are place-holders used by the `call` function. From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function):

```
reverse = $(2) $(1)

foo = $(call reverse,a,b)

Here foo will contain ‘b a’.
```

A2: If we invoke

```
$(call Image/Build/Profile/MT7620a,squashfs)
```

it will expand to

```
$(call BuildFirmware/Default8M/squashfs,squashfs,mt7620a,MT7620a)
```

But `BuildFirmware/Default8M/squashfs` does not appear in your list. The second line defines `BuildFirmware/Default8M/initramfs`, but `BuildFirmware/Default8M/squashfs` must be defined somewhere else.

On the other hand, if we invoke

```
$(call Image/Build/Profile/MT7620a,initramfs)
```

it will expand to

```
$(call BuildFirmware/Default8M/initramfs,initramfs,mt7620a,MT7620a)
```

then

```
$(call BuildFirmware/OF/initramfs,initramfs,initramfs,mt7620a,MT7620a)
```

and then we have to go hunting for the place where `BuildFirmware/OF/initramfs` is defined... Which may eventually lead back to first line.

A3: This use of the slash is hideous, but legal.

Comment: one more thing. so we have:
`BuildFirmware/Default8M/initramfs=$(call BuildFirmware/OF/initramfs,$(1),$(2),$(3),$(4))
`
and :
`$(call BuildFirmware/Default8M/initramfs,initramfs,mt7620a,MT7620a)`
the caller provides 3 params, but the function expects 4. How come it be expanded as: 
`$(call BuildFirmware/OF/initramfs,initramfs,initramfs,mt7620a,MT7620a)` ??